# Reading Part of a Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose, I have the following data-set as numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30])

y = np.array([0, 0.13157895, 0.31578947, 0.40789474, 0.46052632, 0.5, 0.53947368])
```

and I want to read only values corresponding to x = 20, 25, 30. How can I read that using numpy ?

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.searchsorted` can do the job:

```
idx = np.searchsorted(x,[20,25,30]) 
part = y[idx]
```

Note that `x` has to be sorted. In case `x` is not sorted try:

```
idx_sort = np.argsort(x)

xsorted = x[idx_sort]
ysorted = y[idx_sort]

idx = np.searchsorted(xsorted, [20,25,30])
part = y[idx]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can filter `y` using `zip` and `list comprehension`.

```
np.array([v for i, v in zip(x, y) if i in [20, 25, 30]])
#array([0.46052632, 0.5       , 0.53947368])
```

Alternative with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(index=x, data=y).loc[[20, 25, 30]].values
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using [numpy.any](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) to create the boolean mask:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30])
y = np.array([0, 0.13157895, 0.31578947, 0.40789474, 0.46052632, 0.5, 0.53947368])

values = [20,25,30]
m = np.any([x==v for v in values], axis=0)

y[m]
array([0.46052632, 0.5       , 0.53947368])
```

Answer (score -1):

this code will do that:

```
import numpy as np

ind = [np.where(x == num)[0] for num in [20, 25, 30]]
corresponding = y[ind]
```

i believe there is no need to explain, but if you need anything, comment please

Answer (score -2):

Not with numpy but with a dict:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30])
y = np.array([0, 0.13157895, 0.31578947, 0.40789474, 0.46052632, 0.5, 0.53947368])

xy_dict = {}

for j, k in zip(x, y):
    xy_dict[j] = k

print(xy_dict)
```